# inputRichText not updating value on field change

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, spring17

Since Spring 17 my input rich text field is not updating the value anymore when I change the value.

See the following code:

```
 <ui:inputText label="{!v.label}" value="{!v.value}" change="{!c.onInputFieldChange}" />
 <ui:inputRichText label="{!v.label}" cols="50" rows="5" value="{!v.value}" change="{!c.onInputFieldChange}"/>
```

When I type into the inputText field, the value updates fine and updates in the inputRichText field as well. It does not work the other way around.

Am I doing something completely wrong, or is this a bug in Lightning? As far as I can tell, this was working before our sandbox switched to Spring 17.

Comment: Do you have the LockerService enabled in your sandbox? It looks like Rich Text Fields are disabled if LockerService is enabled. https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_general_rich_text_editor_cruc.htm

Comment: @Kyle We have LockerService disabled and we are on Spring 17, where according to this page, any issues should be resolved; https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000001BrF

Comment: This might not be it, but I'll throw it out here anyway...  If you use a custom afterRender, make sure you're calling this.superAfterRender().  I've been bit by not calling this, and then some of my custom input fields appear not to work, and I waste a couple hours figuring it out.  Finally put a sticky note on my monitor to remind me.

Comment: Can you try binding your update on keyup instead of update. http://peterknolle.com/lightning-input-component-value-binding/

Comment: @manjit_singh I've tried several things with the updateOn attribute, with no results.

Comment: @Florissant53 Thanks, but we're not using any custom afterRender's

Comment: @joshuadelange I think your best bet is to open a case with Salesforce. I have heard from a co-worker that it isn't working for them either.

Comment: @joshuadelange did you manage to figure out how to get this working?

Comment: @joshuadelange I used <lightning:inputRichText> instead, that also works with locker service activated

Comment: @whoisthis Thanks for the suggestion. In Spring17, lightning:inputRichText is not properly reading from the conponents value. Same code but with a textarea component is working fine. Very frustrating none of the richtext components are working.

Comment: @joshuadelange yes lightning:inputRichText also sucks :-(

Comment: Most likely it's a bug of Lightning Platform. Did you open a case for Salesforce support? Did they acknowledge the issue?

Comment: @steals I'm quite sure it's a bug as well. We'll look into opening a case and I'll update here.

Comment: Is there any Update on this...I'm facing similar issue as well...I cannot Bind values from controller js to Input rich text.But when I bind values to lightning input its working fine....

Comment: @NaveenDhanaraj yes, salesforce has fixed this issue in one of their updates. See my answer below for our working implementation.

Comment: Yes Its working Fine!!!...Error was on my side..Binding with correct variable solved this for me..Thanks @joshuadelange..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salesforce has fixed this issue in one of their latest updates.

I'm now using the `lightning:inputRichText` successfully:

```
<lightning:inputRichText value="{!v.myVal}" />
```

Docs: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_inputRichText.htm

Answer (score 0):

Seems like potentially a life-cycle issue / native component / quill not destroying correctly. At least in my case, the below seemed to help:

[EDIT] Sorry but after many hours of experimentation I need to refine my answer. The only way I could get the value of lightning:inputRichText to display in all situations was defer the rendering of the component until after the value it was bound to was set.

```
    --- component ---
<!--
- *note*  even though we want this component to always render we are using a conditional
- so that rendering is deferred (while in Edit mode) until after the sObject is retrieved in order
- to resolve the issue. of edit sObject / destroy component.. edit sObject again. component
- does not properly display the note body upon second edit.'
-
- renderRTE is set to true in 2 use cases...
- 1. CREATE MODE - immediately in init when we want to insert a new sObject.
- 2. EDIT MODE - (Deferred) in the helper callback (fired from init)..after retrieving the sObject.
- (after v.svcNote is initialized with either a blank value if no note exists or
- or the existing sObject Note.body of the note associated with the sObject.
-->
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.renderRTE}">
    <lightning:inputRichText aura:id="inputRT" value="{!v.svcNote.Body}"/> 
</aura:if>

--- controller ----
doInit : function(cmp, evt, helper) {
    if (isCreateMode) {
        cmp.set('v.renderRTE', true);
    } else {
        helper.retrieveSObjectData();
    }
}
---- helper ---
retrieveSObjectData: function(cmp,helper) {
    var action=cmp.get('c.retrieveSvcAndNote');
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        cmp.set("v.svcNote",
            {
                "sobjectType": "Note",
                "Id":response.Id,
                "Title": response.Title,
                "ParentId": response.ParentId,
                "Body": response.Body
            }
        );
        cmp.set('v.renderRTE',true);
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
),
```